# How do you redefine strapi db methods such as services.article.find()?

Tags: node.js, strapi

```
async function find(ctx) {
    return await strapi.services.article.find(ctx.query)
}
```

I found this inside my controller, and I am trying to figure out how to redefine the find method and also the dbrepository method that's making the db request to mongoose, so I can add arguments for pagination. I tried to search for a find method, but it wasn't there. How do you do this? I tried to search for the find implementation on my IDE, but I can't, and I am wondering if there's a way to go to the method called so I can actually modify the behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to overwrite the (core) controller. From the docs, https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html#extending-core-controllers:

```
// path: ./src/api/restaurant/controllers/restaurant.js

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::restaurant.restaurant', ({ strapi }) =>  ({
  // Method 1: Creating an entirely custom action
  async exampleAction(ctx) {
    try {
      ctx.body = 'ok';
    } catch (err) {
      ctx.body = err;
    }
  },

  // Method 2: Wrapping a core action (leaves core logic in place)
  async find(ctx) {
    // some custom logic here
    ctx.query = { ...ctx.query, local: 'en' }
    
    // Calling the default core action
    const { data, meta } = await super.find(ctx);

    // some more custom logic
    meta.date = Date.now()

    return { data, meta };
  },

  // Method 3: Replacing a core action
  async findOne(ctx) {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const { query } = ctx;

    const entity = await strapi.service('api::restaurant.restaurant').findOne(id, query);
    const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);

    return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
  }
}));
```

Alternatively, you can add your own custom controller.